# coding a button that loads a specific child in an xml?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, loader, flash-cs6

so im currently creating an interactive trivia quiz in actionscript 3 ,that loads the questions from an external XML file 
the XML format im currently using is :

```
<allq>
  <science>
  <qu></qu>
  <qu></qu>
 </science>

 <sports>
  <qu></qu>
  <qu></qu>
 </sports>

 <tech>
  <qu></qu>
  <qu></qu>
 </tech>

 <health>
  <qu></qu>
  <qu></qu>
 </health>
<allq>
```

so on the first screen there is a menu with all the categories "science,sports,health & tech ...etc" that the user can choose from.
i'm still trying to code the menu buttons so that they load their specific category child from the XML with their respective questions , and if 2 or more categories are selected,their questions will be mixed together since its a randomized quiz.
any help will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to store the index or key name of the node, then query the XML using the node name/index as a key for the new target node, then add the questions to the array/processing script.